# return the number of distance's which is greater than threshold between each point in two arrays

Tags: arrays, optimization, time-complexity

Given

```
distance  = a[i]*a[i]+b[j]*b[j]
```

I use:

```
int[] a = new int[] {3,-1,9};
int[] b = new int[] {100,5,-2};
int res=0;
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
        sum = a[i]*a[i]+b[j]*b[j];
        if(lower<=sum&& sum<=upper)
            res++;
    }
}
return res;
```

Above is my code which has the complexity of `m*n`. Are there any possible ways to optimize the code so that the complexity can be lesser than `n^2`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done using FFT in `O(n log n)` where n is the length of the longer of the two arrays

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of this is `O(m*n)`

You will have to check all the possibilities and hence you cannot optimize it further. Unless you are missing some information on the requirements.

Comment: "hence you cannot optimize it further"
You can make it n log n using FFT